# How android geocoder class works?

Tags: android, google-geocoder

Hi I'm using google native geocoder class to search address. 
Here is my code

```
           final LatLng lowerLeft = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(latLng, DIST_200KM, 225);
           final LatLng upperRight = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(latLng, DIST_200KM, 45);
           List<Address> fromLocationName = geocoder.getFromLocationName(name, 25, lowerLeft.latitude, lowerLeft.longitude, upperRight.latitude, upperRight.longitude);
```

Ex:Expected search is "muruga theatre"
What i get is

```
   Ex: 2) Typed Addr : M   Address[addressLines=[0:"79, Kamaraj Salai, Ilango Nagar, Puducherry, 605013, India"], feature=79, admin=Puducherry, sub-admin=Pondicherry, locality=Puducherry, thoroughfare=Kamaraj Salai, postalCode=605013, countryCode=IN, countryName=India, hasLatitude=true, latitude=11.937229, hasLongitude=true, longitude=79.8231198, phone=null,url=null,extras=null] 

 Boundary lat lng: lower left ---> latlat/lng: (11.303572631938014,79.14103531980237) upper right --->lat/lng: (12.575374031508083,80.4410503605982)
```

Text doesnt match with the result. But the answer is correct. But when i try typing K. The address *kamaraj salai* wont show up.

Could anyone help me in knowing how actually geocoder class works in android.

Comment: Where is the address not showing up? In the response or in your UI? That looks like an UI problem to me.

Comment: The address is not showing up in the result array fromLocationName. I'm only getting one value